# Module parse failed on "Name = undefined"

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, babeljs

I generated javascript-es6 client api with swagger-codegen based on Loopback.io swagger file.

I try to import it in my .vue project but i get the errors like:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (92:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     * @member {String} Name
|     */
|     Name = undefined;
|     /**
|     * @member {Number} LastPrice
 @ ./node_modules/myapi/src/index.js 15:0-36
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/CartVote.vue
 @ ./src/components/CartVote.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/Cart.vue
 @ ./src/components/Cart.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

and

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (229:32)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     * @readonly
|     */
|     static CollectionFormatEnum = {
|         /**
|          * Comma-separated values. Value: <code>csv</code>
@ ./node_modules/myapi/src/index.js 23:0-60
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/CartVote.vue
 @ ./src/components/CartVote.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/Cart.vue
 @ ./src/components/Cart.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

I searched for hours but nothing was similar to this errors.

I use vue-cli generated project, so it uses babel and webpack

What can i do?

**EDIT**

My Babelrc presents

```
"presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2","es2015","stage-0"
  ],
```

Comment: That is not ES6 syntax. Have you enable that experimental syntax proposal in Babel's config?

Comment: @loganfsmyth My api is similart to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/javascript-es6 so i assumed its    ES6, my babel presets are in edit. Is that experimental syntax?

Answer (score 1):

@loganfsmyth is correct, its not ES6 syntax.  I had the same problem and I simply just turning off ES6 with the `useES6` property when generating the client.

One way to do this is using a configuration file containing `"useES6": false`

Then execute `swagger-codegen-cli -c ./config.json ...`